# Could not scan some of the folders contained in “/” (Permission denied)

Tags: permissions, root, restricted-access

### Info

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and created different partitions since I am using 2 different disks (1 SSD and 1 HDD).

When I first booted Ubuntu there were no issues, update as normal when installing a new OS and then rebooted the System.

### Issue

After rebooting the system, on the left side of the screen appeared 4 of what it seems to be storage icons which if I hover them it shows they are: `Filesystem root`, `boot`, `efi`, and `home`.

When I click on one of them it opens the Disk Usage Analyzer app that tells me:

```
Could not scan some of the folders contained in “/”

Error opening directory '/tmp/systemd-private-5fcd0dd16da24355a3f25a32d2f30941-systemd-resolved.service-LyASEf': Permission denied
```

### Question

How can I fix this issue?

#### Edits

I found that the file manager is not present anymore therefore I am not able to have a GUI view of the directories.

### Attachments

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have permission to read what is contained in other users' home folders, and you don't have permission to read some files created by other users. You also do not have permission to read some system files.

In order to get permission, you need to call for superuser privileges.  You can launch the application as the root user by adding `sudo` before the command to launch the application.

This looks similar to `filelight`.  If that's what you're using, run `sudo filelight` in a terminal.  Replace `filelight` with the name of the application you want to run as the root user.

Please note that with superuser privileges, you are giving that application the ultimate power to read, write, execute, and destroy.  Be careful what you are doing. It's often recommended that you not run file manager type applications as the root user.  Determine whether it is really necessary that you give your application access to those files.

Comment: Hey @Nmath, I don't want to open the disk usage analyser app with superuser privilege. That app opens only because I click on the icons appeared on the left (the grey optic-disk readers). The issue is that they appeared and when I open them it opens that app that tells me that I can't access a few folders in the `/root` and `/home` directories

Comment: Yes I just explained why you can't access those files and folders without sufficient permissions. If you have no need to delve into those folders, you can just ignore the warning.